# MySQL new join when result of existing join is null

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables: `cat`, and `cat_name`.

**`cat`**:

```
id
--
1
2
```

**`cat_name`**:

```
id | cat_id | locale | name
---------------------------
1  | 1      | en     | John
2  | 1      | fr     | Jean
3  | 2      | en     | Jane
```

My SQL to get a list of cats and their names for a given locale is:

```
SELECT `cat`.`id` AS `id`, `cat_name`.`name` AS `name` FROM `cat` 
LEFT JOIN `cat_name` ON `cat`.`id` = `cat_name`.`cat_id` AND `cat_name`.`locale` = 'fr'
```

This works, but when a cat's name has no translation for a given locale (e.g. in the above example, if we want to get the `fr` name for cat `2`), the `name` value is, as expected, `null`.

What I can't figure out is how, given a fallback locale (e.g. `en`), to check if the result of the `JOIN` is `null`, and if so to then get the `name` of the fallback locale. I.e. in the above example, to return a cat name of `Jane` even if the set locale is `fr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the fallback language in a `JOIN` and then use `COALESCE` to select that value if there is no value for a given language e.g.

```
SELECT `cat`.`id` AS `id`, COALESCE(`c2`.`name`, `c1`.`name`) AS `name` 
FROM `cat` 
JOIN `cat_name` c1 ON `cat`.`id` = `c1`.`cat_id` AND `c1`.`locale` = 'en'
LEFT JOIN `cat_name` c2 ON `cat`.`id` = `c2`.`cat_id` AND `c2`.`locale` = 'fr'
```

Output:

```
id  name
1   Jean
2   Jane
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mmNfCbqB676U6CwpV6sofp/0)